# 'DateValue' is not a recognized built-in function name Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

What is the alternate of MS Access DateValue function in Sql Server
Here is the Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ss.FileName 
FROM SubmitSheets AS ss 
WHERE 1=1 AND 1=1 AND 1=1 AND 
ss.UpdateTimeA >= DateValue('2014/11/03') AND
ss.UpdateTimeA < DateAdd("d", 1, DateValue('2016/01/06')) AND
(1=1) AND 1=1 ORDER BY ss.FileName
```

And Here is the Error

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
'DateValue' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

This query works fine in MS Access

Comment: Why do you have 1=1 5 times in your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need that. Instead of

```
DateValue('2014/11/03')
```

use the date itself

```
'2014/11/03'
```